# Android Broadcast Receiver is showing permission error even it is set

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am having trouble setting up `Broadcastreceiver` on `SMS Receive`. I have set all permissions but still it is giving the following permission error

> .../system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving
>   Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x19000010
>   (has extras) } to me.jatinsoni.broadcastreceiver/.MyBroadcastReceiver
>   requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender
>   com.android.phone (uid 1001)

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastreceiver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### MyBroadcastReceiver

```
...

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Receiver Triggered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "Broadcast Receiver Triggered!");
    }
}
```

### Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.broadcastreceiver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: You  need to ask run time permission for `RECEIVE_SMS` my friend

Comment: @NileshRathod any reference how to do it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801880/7666442

Comment: Cool.. thanks .. let me check.. one more thing. does android required runtime permission on Marshmallow and above?

Comment: Yes the run time permission is required on Marshmallow and above android version

Comment: I see.. one more thing.. in my case where I should write the runtimre permission code? I mean on the receiver class or main activity?

Comment: better to use **`SMS Retriever API`**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433987/7666442   because  of [Google’s restrictions on SMS/Call Log permissions](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-restriction-sms-call-log-permissions/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188722/discussion-between-code-lover-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 2):

In Android 6 and above defining the permission in the manifest, not enough, you need to ask for the permission at runtime.

You can use this function in your activity class:

```
final int REQ_PERMISSION_SMS = 1;

private void requestSmsPermission() {
   String permission = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
   int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
   if ( grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       String[] permission_list = new String[1];
       permission_list[0] = permission;
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, REQ_PERMISSION_SMS);
   }
}
```

And also you can add the following callback for the check that, does user allows you to receive SMS or not:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_PERMISSION_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //user allow you to recieve sms
            } else {
               //user don't allow you to recieve sms
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reference code..let me try to set it for multiple permissions.

Comment: @CodeLover You're welcome if you had a problem with these codes let me know.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it for me after trying a few other answers in other similar questions